# How to serve same static .html file for all dynamic urls using Play framework and Java?

Tags: java, html, scala, playframework

I am trying to serve a static html file let's call it `index.html` for all dynamic urls like `/tachyon/someId`. This `someId` is generated dynamically. I have tried multiple ways to do this but all failed. This is what all I have tried.

- Tried adding `controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="index.html")` for GET url `/tachyon/*someId`. This failed saying missing parameter someId.
- Tried rendering `index.html` through render. This also failed since `index.html` is not a `scala.html` template.
- Tried returning `routes.Assets.at("index.html")` through controller. This also failed since I want to return `Result` but the return type for the method is different.
- Tried returning `ok(routes.Assets.at("index.html")` through controller. This also failed saying not a valid Call for ok.

It would be better if there is a way to do this through controller and returning `Result` from method in `task helper` class to `task` since I am returning `Promise<Result>` from method in `task` class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Twirl to generate the page. Since you want a static html, you can ignore the parameter in the body.

so in routes, add:

```
GET /tachyon/*someId   somecontroller.index(someId)
```

in the controller's index function, you can return

```
Ok(views.html.somepage(someId))
```

And you create a somepage.scala.html Twirl function in views folder, but do not use someId in the body.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Not sure if it is the correct solution or not. I rendered the `index.html` by converting it to a byte array and then using `ok` to render using `ByteArrayInputStream`. Something like this.

```
File file = Play.getFile("path to the file", Play.current());
byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(file));
return ok(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray)).as("text/html");
```

Let me know if there is any better way to do this without using scala templating.

Thanks